# Why is this script looping on the first line of the txt file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, read

```
#!/bin/bash
usernameFile="/home/netadmin/username_list.txt"

logFile="/var/log/netvpn-mag-archive/netvpn-mag-20160"

  while read -r line < $usernameFile; do
    if [[ "$line" != " " ]]; then
            zgrep -w "$line" "$logFile"* >> grep_output.txt
    fi
  done < "$usernameFile"
```

with this script I want to grep against the log file every user in the usernamefile. Currently, the script is looping through the first username over and over again. I need it to stop after going through all files in the logfile directory and move to the next name in the list.

Comment: After fixing the double input (already answered), you can put `>> grep_output.txt` outside the while loop, so you dont open/close `grep_output.txt` for every line in the input.

Answer (score 6):

There are two place where you input "$usernameFile": one in the global loop, the other in read.

```
while read -r line < $usernameFile; do

done < "$usernameFile"
```

you should input it only in global loop I think.  (In other words, only put it after "done".)

Comment: this is correct answer. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @pdickson26 Since this answer worked for you, you should [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the check mark to the left. This marks the question as *answered* and (with upvotes) is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.
Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!

Answer (score -1):

```
cat "$usernameFile" | while read line;
do
   if [[ "$line" != " " ]]; then
     zgrep -w "$line" "$logFile"* >> grep_output.txt
   fi
done
```